# I cannot solve theT T-SQL error. T-SQL says I have to convert VARCHAR value GG?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server Express 2014. 
I have written the below query. SQL says this below error message and not sure what to do. 
"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'GG' to data type int"
Not sure how to solve this either using CAST or CONVERT.

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
USE AdventureWorks2012  
GO

DECLARE @Number01 AS INT
DECLARE @Number02 AS INT
DECLARE @Number03 AS INT
DECLARE @Number04 AS INT
DECLARE @Number05 AS INT
DECLARE @Number06 AS INT
DECLARE @Number07 AS INT

SET @Number01 = 150
SET @Number02 = 200
SET @Number03 = 350
SET @Number04 = 450
SET @Number05 = 550
SET @Number06 = 650
SET @Number07 = 800


SELECT  A.ProductID  ,A.Name  ,A.ProductModelID  ,A.ProductNumber ,A.MakeFlag  ,A.Color  ,A.SafetyStockLevel ,A.StandardCost ,A.ListPrice,A.DaysToManufacture ,A.SellEndDate ,A.ModifiedDate ,A.ListPrice
,B.Name ,B.ListPrice ,B.Adjusted_List_Price ,C.ProductDescriptionID ,C.Description ,C.ModifiedDate ,D.ProductID ,D.StartDate ,D.EndDate ,D.ListPrice ,D.ModifiedDate, E.Name,E.CatalogDescription,E.ModifiedDate ,F.ReferenceOrderID ,F.TransactionDate ,F.TransactionID ,F.Quantity
,IIF(A.ListPrice >=@Number01,@Number01 *@Number02 + @Number03, 'GG')

FROM  [Production].[Product] AS A 
INNER JOIN [Production].[Product_2] AS B
ON A.Name = B.Name

INNER JOIN  [Production].[ProductDescription] AS C
ON A.ProductID = C.ProductDescriptionID

INNER JOIN  [Production].[ProductListPriceHistory] AS D
ON A.ProductID = D.ProductID

INNER JOIN   [Production].[ProductModel] AS E
ON A.ProductModelID = E.ProductModelID

FULL JOIN [Production].[TransactionHistory] AS F
ON A.ProductID = F.ProductID

WHERE A.ProductModelID IS NOT NULL
AND A.Color IS NOT NULL AND F.Quantity IS NOT NULL
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Can someone please advise as I am really confused.??
Thanks

Shrik

Comment: Production.Product.ListPrice in the AdventureWorks DB is a money type.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are using two different data types for your TRUE and FALSE evaluation of IIF. You can use something like this:

```
IIF(A.ListPrice >=@Number01,CAST((@Number01 *@Number02 + @Number03) AS nvarchar(50)), 'GG')
```

By casting the integers as varchar, you can use the string 'GG' in the same column.

Comment: Awesome ! Great help!

Comment: Out of interest - what do you think of my SQL Skills ??

Comment: You should look up why EXISTS outperforms joins that look for non-null and use CASE statements instead of the IIF function which was included in SQL to aid in transitioning from Access.

Comment: Hi Anthony Thank you for the feedback. Could you give me an example of this could could be used in what I have done please for better clarification. Thanks. Shrik